# TeX Maker can't compile brazilian portuguese words (LaTeX)

Tags: texmaker, mac

guys!

I'm new to this world, so please take it easy on me, right?

I'm trying to do my graduation thesis on LaTeX, 'cause I think it just get prettier with this thing, but then I faced this kind of bug.

I was already doing that, but something went wrong this morning, when I tried to compile it again, so all the accents are gone (ç, ~, ^ etc.).

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}



\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Impossibilidade de expropriação de bitcoins e as estruturas de incentivo para o cumprimento voluntário da execução}

\author{Pedro Paulo Alves Corrêa dos Passos}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Introdução}

Desde a criação da moeda, tem-se maior efetividade das atividades mercantis. Todavia, a sua criação sempre fora centralizada, quando oficiais, às mãos de governantes em sentido amplo, de modo a manter o poder sobre o mercado, por menor que seja, em estruturas que se assemelhavam à estrutura do Estado, até à própria estrutura estatal dos dias hodiernos.

Em verdade, a centralização desse poder expõe a dependência dos súditos e cidadãos às ações dos governantes e os efeitos nefastos que suas ações podem proporcionar à economia de um povo. São exemplos desse fenômeno a Grécia em 2013, os Estados Unidos na crise de 1929 com a liberação de crédito oriunda de ações governamentais e os Estados Unidos na crise de 2008, o Brasil na chamada “década perdida” e o Brasil a partir de 2013, entre tantos outros que se resumem basicamente à existência de um Banco Central que controle políticas monetárias.

Em 2008, um programador conhecido pelo pseudônimo Satoshi Nakamoto criou o protocolo do então chamado sistema Bitcoin, baseado em transações sem intermediários, em uma moeda não lastreada e em uma economia descentralizada, à parte de qualquer instituição central que gerencie a moeda.

O Bitcoin ganha destaque e expõe benefícios como menores custos de transação, maior acesso a serviços financeiros básicos e estimulo à inovação financeira, porquanto não dependa de intermediários, não seja controlado por nenhum poder capaz de impedir negociações ou manipular a moeda e o protocolo seja capaz de incentivar transações criptografadas, inclusive de ações de empresas ou outros ativos.

Os maiores desafios da criptomoeda se referem à volatilidade e ao uso para fins criminosos. Como qualquer outra moeda ou ativo, notícias e anúncios positivos acerca do Bitcoin fizeram com que novos investidores o buscassem, empurrando seu preço para cima e criando uma “bolha”. ULRICH (2014) traz que desde 2011 foram ao menos cinco ajustes de preço significativos. Quanto ao seu uso para fins criminosos, tem-se o exemplo do mercado negro Silk Road, que operava na deep web para transação de bens e serviços ilícitos, culminando na prisão de seu administrador Ross Ulbricht e um movimento promovido por senadores norte-americanos pela caçada ao Tor e ao Bitcoin.

\newpage

\section{Execução e cumprimento de sentença}

\subsection{Origens}

\subsection{Meios de expropriação}

\subsubsection{Penhor e leilão}

\subsubsection{Adjudicação}

\section{Bitcoin}

Antes de, propriamente, dissertar sobre o sistema Bitcoin, faz-se necessário tratar da ideia própria de moeda e seus desdobramentos no desenvolvimento da criptomoeda. É importante esclarecer que o viés econômico é mister no sentido de embasar a teoria sobre a qual o Direito se debruçará no invariável momento de sua regulação.

\subsection{O que é moeda}

Para conceituar moeda, deve-se ter em vista que o uso cotidiano do termo deve ser posto de lado. FREDERIC MISHKIN (2000) nos traz:

\begin{quote}
A palavra moeda, conforme é usada em conversações diárias, pode significar muitas coisas, mas para os economistas ela tem um significado muito específico. \\ (...) \\ Os economistas definem moeda (também chamada de oferta de moeda) como qualquer coisa que seja geralmente aceita em pagamento por bens ou serviços ou no pagamento final de dívidas. \\ (...) \\ Definir moeda meramente como dinheiro é muito limitado para os economistas. Uma vez que cheques também são aceitos como pagamentos para compras, depósitos em contas correntes são considerados moedas também. Frequentemente uma definição ainda mais ampla de moeda é necessária porque outros itens, como depósitos de poupança, podem funcionar como moeda se puderem ser rápida e facilmente convertidos em dinheiro ou depósitos de conta corrente. (...)
\end{quote}

É de se notar, portanto, que a conceituação da moeda não se dá de modo uníssono e MISHKIN (2000) trata, portanto, da moeda sob a perspectiva de suas funções primordiais: como meio de pagamento, como unidade de conta e como reserva de valor, sendo que a “função como meio de pagamento é o que distingue a moeda de outros ativos como ações, bônus e casas”.

O aperfeiçoamento da res enquanto moeda se dá, a priori, pela capacidade de utilizá-la como forma de pagamento por bens e serviços. Um primeiro questionamento que se poderia fazer seria no sentido de buscar entender a necessidade de se ter algo como moeda, se os próprios bens ou serviços são intercambiáveis per se. 

Ocorre que, para fazê-lo, indivíduos deveriam se encontrar com interesses recíprocos em seus bens ou serviços a oferecer. A moeda surge para servir como intermediária nas trocas, em civilizações pautadas pelo escambo. A partir do momento em que há uma referência para as negociações, não há mais a necessidade das buscas por interesses recíprocos. Trata-se de segurança, quanto à referência de valor, e de uma análise de custo benefício.

\subsubsection{Moeda como meio de pagamento e reserva de valor}

A res, para se configurar como moeda, em atenção à função de servir como meio de pagamento, deve observar alguns pontos, dentre os quais MISHKIN (2000) traz: deve ser de fácil padronização, grande aceitabilidade e divisibilidade, deve ser fácil de carregar e não deve se deteriorar rapidamente.

O primeiro ponto diz respeito à simplificação no processo de determinar o valor da moeda. Dessa forma, seguindo um padrão de clareza, a moeda facilmente é criada quando a personalização da res torna fácil a identificação do valor que tem em si mesma.

Quanto à aceitabilidade e divisibilidade, tem-se que a moeda deve ser aceita pelas pessoas, de modo que a facilidade em realizar as transações comerciais se concretiza na medida em que é aceita pelo mercado. A divisibilidade, noutro giro, se refere ao troco, isto é, garantir que transações de pequeno valor comercial ocorram, também.

A facilidade de carregar se resume à praticidade que faz parte da ideia própria de moeda. Ela surge como meio para facilitar transações, não para dificultá-las. Nesse sentido, a moeda não pode ser de difícil manuseio, de modo a criar novos óbices às negociações.

A necessidade de não se deteriorar rapidamente resume a ideia de reserva de valor. A ideia é que mantenha o poder de compra no curso do tempo. Sendo o ativo com maior liquidez, por ser o próprio meio de pagamento, deve preservar, em si, seu valor.

Por estes critérios, qualquer coisa se poderia transformar em moeda, e de fato a assertiva está correta. MISHKIN (2000) nos elucida:

\begin{quote}
As formas de moeda que satisfizeram estes critérios tomaram muitas formas incomuns através da história humana, estendendo-se desde wampum (cordões de contas) usados pelos nativos americanos até tabaco e uísque, usados pelos primeiros colonizadores americanos, a cigarros, usados em campos de prisioneiros durante a Segunda Guerra Mundial. A diversidade de formas de moeda que têm se desenvolvido através dos anos é tanto um testemunho da inventividade da raça humano quanto do desenvolvimento de ferramentas e linguagem.
\end{quote}

Destarte, a moeda é criada com o objetivo de facilitar negociações, aperfeiçoar os processos mercantis e dar maior efetividade ao mercado, instituto existente desde os primórdios das civilizações.

\subsection{O que é bitcoin}

Bitcoin, conforme leciona ULRICH (2014), é um sistema de código aberto que se pauta por transações de ponto a ponto (ou peer-to-peer, em inglês) em que a unidade monetária a que se referem tais transações recebe o nome do próprio sistema: bitcoin.

Algumas características devem ser ressalvadas, como o fato de ser um sistema descentralizado (por isso ser ponto a ponto), estritamente digital e principiologicamente sem intermediários.

A descentralização diz respeito a não existir um controlador central do sistema, mas o sistema é quem se autorregula, pelos seus usuários. De fato, por manter um livro-razão público em que são conferidas as transações de bitcoins, a verificação de autenticidade da moeda se dá pelos próprios usuários.

A moeda é estritamente digital porque é, basicamente, um protocolo, um conjunto de regras que determinam a existência de cada moeda digital e por não possuir correspondente físico, em papel-moeda, o que será abordado em tópico oportuno.

Quanto a ser principiologicamente livre de intermediários, tem-se a ideia que deu origem ao sistema: ser capaz de realizar transações de modo seguro sem que seja necessário um terceiro de confiança, como o PayPal ou o PagSeguro, para garantir que o dinheiro não seja gasto duas vezes, o problema do “gasto duplo”.

\subsection{Como funciona o bitcoin}

O Bitcoin, porquanto seja um sistema essencialmente de pagamentos, não de registros, funciona com base em criptografia de chave pública. É dizer que, quando criptografada, o proprietário da moeda recebe duas chaves, uma pública e uma privada. No momento da transação, a chave pública é anotada no blockchain, com a anotação de que fora assinada pela chave privada pelo anterior proprietário.

\section{Estruturas de incentivo para o cumprimento voluntário da execução}

\section{Conclusão}

\newpage

\section{Bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

And as result I got this:

[image: cover]
[image: introduction]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I'd recommend not to load `times`, which is obsolete. Use a times clone, like TeX  Gyre Termes, via `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` instead.

Comment: Some comments: you really don't need all this: `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}` (ugly and redundant)
and this: 
`\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}` is redundant. If you _really_ need to follow `ABNT` rules, there is a class and some packages for that. `article` isn't really the easiest or best option for your job. And use `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` as Bernard said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the font encoding for the input file and the output with the two lines

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <=========================================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <============================================
```

in the preamble.

With the complete following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <=========================================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <============================================

\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Impossibilidade de expropriação de bitcoins e as estruturas de incentivo para o cumprimento voluntário da execução}

\author{Pedro Paulo Alves Corrêa dos Passos}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Introdução}

Desde a criação da moeda, tem-se maior efetividade das atividades mercantis. Todavia, a sua criação sempre fora centralizada, quando oficiais, às mãos de governantes em sentido amplo, de modo a manter o poder sobre o mercado, por menor que seja, em estruturas que se assemelhavam à estrutura do Estado, até à própria estrutura estatal dos dias hodiernos.

Em verdade, a centralização desse poder expõe a dependência dos súditos e cidadãos às ações dos governantes e os efeitos nefastos que suas ações podem proporcionar à economia de um povo. São exemplos desse fenômeno a Grécia em 2013, os Estados Unidos na crise de 1929 com a liberação de crédito oriunda de ações governamentais e os Estados Unidos na crise de 2008, o Brasil na chamada “década perdida” e o Brasil a partir de 2013, entre tantos outros que se resumem basicamente à existência de um Banco Central que controle políticas monetárias.

Em 2008, um programador conhecido pelo pseudônimo Satoshi Nakamoto criou o protocolo do então chamado sistema Bitcoin, baseado em transações sem intermediários, em uma moeda não lastreada e em uma economia descentralizada, à parte de qualquer instituição central que gerencie a moeda.

O Bitcoin ganha destaque e expõe benefícios como menores custos de transação, maior acesso a serviços financeiros básicos e estimulo à inovação financeira, porquanto não dependa de intermediários, não seja controlado por nenhum poder capaz de impedir negociações ou manipular a moeda e o protocolo seja capaz de incentivar transações criptografadas, inclusive de ações de empresas ou outros ativos.

Os maiores desafios da criptomoeda se referem à volatilidade e ao uso para fins criminosos. Como qualquer outra moeda ou ativo, notícias e anúncios positivos acerca do Bitcoin fizeram com que novos investidores o buscassem, empurrando seu preço para cima e criando uma “bolha”. ULRICH (2014) traz que desde 2011 foram ao menos cinco ajustes de preço significativos. Quanto ao seu uso para fins criminosos, tem-se o exemplo do mercado negro Silk Road, que operava na deep web para transação de bens e serviços ilícitos, culminando na prisão de seu administrador Ross Ulbricht e um movimento promovido por senadores norte-americanos pela caçada ao Tor e ao Bitcoin.

\newpage

\section{Execução e cumprimento de sentença}

\subsection{Origens}

\subsection{Meios de expropriação}

\subsubsection{Penhor e leilão}

\subsubsection{Adjudicação}

\section{Bitcoin}

Antes de, propriamente, dissertar sobre o sistema Bitcoin, faz-se necessário tratar da ideia própria de moeda e seus desdobramentos no desenvolvimento da criptomoeda. É importante esclarecer que o viés econômico é mister no sentido de embasar a teoria sobre a qual o Direito se debruçará no invariável momento de sua regulação.

\subsection{O que é moeda}

Para conceituar moeda, deve-se ter em vista que o uso cotidiano do termo deve ser posto de lado. FREDERIC MISHKIN (2000) nos traz:

\begin{quote}
A palavra moeda, conforme é usada em conversações diárias, pode significar muitas coisas, mas para os economistas ela tem um significado muito específico. \\ (...) \\ Os economistas definem moeda (também chamada de oferta de moeda) como qualquer coisa que seja geralmente aceita em pagamento por bens ou serviços ou no pagamento final de dívidas. \\ (...) \\ Definir moeda meramente como dinheiro é muito limitado para os economistas. Uma vez que cheques também são aceitos como pagamentos para compras, depósitos em contas correntes são considerados moedas também. Frequentemente uma definição ainda mais ampla de moeda é necessária porque outros itens, como depósitos de poupança, podem funcionar como moeda se puderem ser rápida e facilmente convertidos em dinheiro ou depósitos de conta corrente. (...)
\end{quote}

É de se notar, portanto, que a conceituação da moeda não se dá de modo uníssono e MISHKIN (2000) trata, portanto, da moeda sob a perspectiva de suas funções primordiais: como meio de pagamento, como unidade de conta e como reserva de valor, sendo que a “função como meio de pagamento é o que distingue a moeda de outros ativos como ações, bônus e casas”.

O aperfeiçoamento da res enquanto moeda se dá, a priori, pela capacidade de utilizá-la como forma de pagamento por bens e serviços. Um primeiro questionamento que se poderia fazer seria no sentido de buscar entender a necessidade de se ter algo como moeda, se os próprios bens ou serviços são intercambiáveis per se. 

Ocorre que, para fazê-lo, indivíduos deveriam se encontrar com interesses recíprocos em seus bens ou serviços a oferecer. A moeda surge para servir como intermediária nas trocas, em civilizações pautadas pelo escambo. A partir do momento em que há uma referência para as negociações, não há mais a necessidade das buscas por interesses recíprocos. Trata-se de segurança, quanto à referência de valor, e de uma análise de custo benefício.

\subsubsection{Moeda como meio de pagamento e reserva de valor}

A res, para se configurar como moeda, em atenção à função de servir como meio de pagamento, deve observar alguns pontos, dentre os quais MISHKIN (2000) traz: deve ser de fácil padronização, grande aceitabilidade e divisibilidade, deve ser fácil de carregar e não deve se deteriorar rapidamente.

O primeiro ponto diz respeito à simplificação no processo de determinar o valor da moeda. Dessa forma, seguindo um padrão de clareza, a moeda facilmente é criada quando a personalização da res torna fácil a identificação do valor que tem em si mesma.

Quanto à aceitabilidade e divisibilidade, tem-se que a moeda deve ser aceita pelas pessoas, de modo que a facilidade em realizar as transações comerciais se concretiza na medida em que é aceita pelo mercado. A divisibilidade, noutro giro, se refere ao troco, isto é, garantir que transações de pequeno valor comercial ocorram, também.

A facilidade de carregar se resume à praticidade que faz parte da ideia própria de moeda. Ela surge como meio para facilitar transações, não para dificultá-las. Nesse sentido, a moeda não pode ser de difícil manuseio, de modo a criar novos óbices às negociações.

A necessidade de não se deteriorar rapidamente resume a ideia de reserva de valor. A ideia é que mantenha o poder de compra no curso do tempo. Sendo o ativo com maior liquidez, por ser o próprio meio de pagamento, deve preservar, em si, seu valor.

Por estes critérios, qualquer coisa se poderia transformar em moeda, e de fato a assertiva está correta. MISHKIN (2000) nos elucida:

\begin{quote}
As formas de moeda que satisfizeram estes critérios tomaram muitas formas incomuns através da história humana, estendendo-se desde wampum (cordões de contas) usados pelos nativos americanos até tabaco e uísque, usados pelos primeiros colonizadores americanos, a cigarros, usados em campos de prisioneiros durante a Segunda Guerra Mundial. A diversidade de formas de moeda que têm se desenvolvido através dos anos é tanto um testemunho da inventividade da raça humano quanto do desenvolvimento de ferramentas e linguagem.
\end{quote}

Destarte, a moeda é criada com o objetivo de facilitar negociações, aperfeiçoar os processos mercantis e dar maior efetividade ao mercado, instituto existente desde os primórdios das civilizações.

\subsection{O que é bitcoin}

Bitcoin, conforme leciona ULRICH (2014), é um sistema de código aberto que se pauta por transações de ponto a ponto (ou peer-to-peer, em inglês) em que a unidade monetária a que se referem tais transações recebe o nome do próprio sistema: bitcoin.

Algumas características devem ser ressalvadas, como o fato de ser um sistema descentralizado (por isso ser ponto a ponto), estritamente digital e principiologicamente sem intermediários.

A descentralização diz respeito a não existir um controlador central do sistema, mas o sistema é quem se autorregula, pelos seus usuários. De fato, por manter um livro-razão público em que são conferidas as transações de bitcoins, a verificação de autenticidade da moeda se dá pelos próprios usuários.

A moeda é estritamente digital porque é, basicamente, um protocolo, um conjunto de regras que determinam a existência de cada moeda digital e por não possuir correspondente físico, em papel-moeda, o que será abordado em tópico oportuno.

Quanto a ser principiologicamente livre de intermediários, tem-se a ideia que deu origem ao sistema: ser capaz de realizar transações de modo seguro sem que seja necessário um terceiro de confiança, como o PayPal ou o PagSeguro, para garantir que o dinheiro não seja gasto duas vezes, o problema do “gasto duplo”.

\subsection{Como funciona o bitcoin}

O Bitcoin, porquanto seja um sistema essencialmente de pagamentos, não de registros, funciona com base em criptografia de chave pública. É dizer que, quando criptografada, o proprietário da moeda recebe duas chaves, uma pública e uma privada. No momento da transação, a chave pública é anotada no blockchain, com a anotação de que fora assinada pela chave privada pelo anterior proprietário.

\section{Estruturas de incentivo para o cumprimento voluntário da execução}

\section{Conclusão}

\newpage

\section{Bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting first page]